# Media player stops working after playing some files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I have an Android app and I want to play different sounds. My code works fine but after playing some sounds it stops playing more sounds.
My click listener is in a ListView, So it loops for different sounds.
I think the problem is because of creating and stoping, but I don't understand how to fix it?

Can anyone please help with my code?

```
 MediaPlayer mp;
 holder.alphabetSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
            }
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(activity,sound[index]));
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Logcat:

```
2019-10-26 20:44:28.737 1319-8893/? E/MP3Extractor: Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.
2019-10-26 20:44:28.744 1315-1946/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(52300a9:google.mp3.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-10-26 20:44:28.751 1306-9450/? E/AudioFlinger: no more track names available
2019-10-26 20:44:28.751 1306-9450/? E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2019-10-26 20:44:28.751 1320-10055/? E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
2019-10-26 20:44:28.751 1320-10055/? E/AudioSink: Unable to create audio track
2019-10-26 20:44:28.752 1320-10052/? E/NuPlayer: received error(0xffffffed) from audio decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
2019-10-26 20:44:28.752 9789-9801/ir.lariha.englishanimals E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
2019-10-26 20:44:28.752 9789-9789/ir.lariha.englishanimals E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)
```

Comment: Try to call release() after stop() to free resources. Be sure that sound[index] is exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void startMP(final Context context){
        if(mp == null){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create( context, R.raw.ringtone);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    stopMP(context);
                }
            });
        }
        mp.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);
    }

    private void stopMP(Context context) {
        if(mp != null) {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
            Toast.makeText(context , "song is stopped " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

use this methods by your own necessity.
As you think ,problem is in your creating and stopping procedure. I think if you follow that , it would be helpful.

Comment: It'd be helpful (for future visitors as also) if you elaborate on your answer.

Comment: I did it now. Thank you.

Comment: @MuktaGhosh thankyou , i tested it . but the problem still exists . it stops after playing around 20 sounds , if it click on them a little fast. (each sound is about 2 or 3 seconds)